# Could anyone explain why this fork execution prints 8 times my text?

Tags: c, printf, fork

I can't understand why it prints 8 times the text. In my conception it should prints just 2 times.
Could anynone help me?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    pid_t x=0;
    pid_t y=0;
    x=fork();
    if(y>0)
        fork();
    if(x==0)
        y=fork();
    fork();
    if(y==0){
        fork();
        printf("Some text\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Only twice, with that many fork calls!! Did you try adding some `printf`s to trace the control flow?

Comment: This looks like a school assignment to me. What's the purpose of this question?

Comment: Yep, it's a school assignment. I have to identify how many times the text is printed.

Comment: `void main()` is an invalid signature for a hosted environment, invoking undefined behaviour. The simplest legal signature is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Paul Rooney I didn't add prints to trace, but it was a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x = fork();` is executed and 2 processes are running.

`if (y>0) fork();` will never be executed.

`if (x==0) y=fork();` will be executed by the child process so now there are 3 processes running. For the initial parent `y` is still `0`. For the child it's `y == child_child's pid` and for the child's child it's `y==0`.

All 3 processes will execute `fork()` so there are 6 processes in total, 4 of these have `y==0` in their memory.

These 4 processes fork again, so there are 8 processes and they execute that `printf(...);`

Comment: ok elikatsis, I didn't know that each process had its own variable y with 0 value, That was the confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Have in mind that every forked process gets a copy of the parent's memory as it is right before the execution of fork! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I modify the code to have more debugging print.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "unistd.h"
int main() {
    pid_t x=0;
    pid_t y=0;

    printf("FORK X \n");
    x=fork();

    if(y>0) {
        printf("FORK 1 \n");
        fork();
    }

    if(x==0) {
        printf("FORK 2 \n");
        y=fork();
    }

    printf("FORK 3 \n");
    fork();
    if(y==0){
        printf("FORK 4 \n");
        fork();
        printf("Some text\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the output, and every "FORK 4" will result TWO "Some text" since there is a fork afterwards:

Pancake:tmp greedy52$ ./a.out

```
FORK X 
FORK 3 
FORK 4 
FORK 2 
FORK 4 
Some text
Some text
FORK 3 
FORK 3 
Some text
Some text
FORK 4 
Some text
FORK 4 
Some text
Some text
Some text
```

The 4 "FORK 4" are reached by (each successful fork() call creates two process A and B):

1. @x=fork() -> x != 0 and @FORK 3 fork A
2. @x=fork() -> x != 0 and @FORK 3 fork B
3. @x=fork() -> x = 0 and @y=fork() -> y = 0 and @FORK 3 fork A
4. @x=fork() -> x = 0 and @y=fork() -> y = 0 and @FORK 3 fork B

The @x=fork() -> x = 0 and @y=fork() -> y!= 0 branch doesn't generate any "Some text".

```
FORK X --------> x != 0 -------------------------------> FORK 3 A -----> FORK 4 A (Some text)
          |              |                                          |--> FORK 4 B (Some text)
          |              |
          |              |-----------------------------> FORK 3 B -----> FORK 4 A (Some text)
          |                                                         |--> FORK 4 B (Some text)
          |
          |
          |----> x == 0 -----> FORK 2 A ( y = 0 ) -----> FORK 3 A -----> FORK 4 A (Some text)
                         |                                          |--> FORK 4 B (Some text)
                         |                         |---> FORK 3 B -----> FORK 4 A (Some text)
                         |                                          |--> FORK 4 B (Some text)
                         |
                         |---> FORK 2 B (y != 0 ) -----> FORK 3 A -----> XXX bad end
                                                   |---> FORK 3 B -----> XXX bad end
```